# How to Add Space on Text Inside <div> Using CSS when Padding Not Working as Expected

Tags: html, css, text

I'm trying to adjust the position of a `<div>` inside another element, but it seems like the padding isn't having the desired effect.

How can I position my text to align with the red line in the image below? Padding doesn't seem to work for some reason. Thank you!

I'm attempting to position the text, as shown in the image below, to align with the red line:

[image: Position of text]

HTML:

```
<header>
  biography
</header>
<div class="hero">
   <div class="title">
     Lorem ipsum dolor si amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero{
 background-color:#5FCF80;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
title{
padding: px 20px;
 display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

title is a class so css selector will start with . and correct padding syntax.

```
.title{
  padding: 40px;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 font-size: 19px;
}
```

```css
.hero{
 background-color:#5FCF80;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  /*
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  */
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}
header{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.title{
padding: 40px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
Landing page
-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  biography
</header>
<div class="hero">
   <div class="title">
     Lorem ipsum dolor si amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: may i know why you are adding vertical-align:middle and dispaly:table-cell

Comment: @Naila did not want to change the css what the OP provided other than the issues which was causing the code to not work. but yeah valid point.

Answer (score 2):

css syntax error `padding: px 20px` class name add `.title`

```
.title{
 padding: 10px 20px;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 font-size: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height of `.title` to make text vertically centered.

```css
.hero{
  background-color:#5FCF80;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
header{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.title{
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 80vh;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Landing page
-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  biography
</header>
<div class="hero">
   <div class="title">
     Lorem ipsum dolor si amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is one more solution where `.hero` set as `table-cell`, thus `.title` has less attributes to define.

```css
.hero{
  background-color:#5FCF80;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
header{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.title{
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Landing page
-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  biography
</header>
<div class="hero">
   <div class="title">
     Lorem ipsum dolor si amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more perfect solution .

```
.hero{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#5FCF80;
  height: 80vh;
  display:block;
}
.hero .title{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 }
```